# Using php functions to display html

Tags: php, html, function, templating

I am Working on a little project and I want to apply some sort of templating to display content in between a master template file when included on each page without using any templating engine. Currently i have the following pages.

**layout.template.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <!-- page content displays here -->
  <?php show_content(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php function show_content(){ ?>
<div>
    <h1>Home page</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<?php } 
include 'layout.template.php';
?>
```

**second.php**

```
<?php function show_content(){ ?>
<div>
    <h1>Second page</h1>
    <p>some other content</p>
</div>
<?php }
include 'layout.template.php';
?>
```

i use the show_content() function to define the html that would be rendered into the layout.template.php file on each page. When layout.template.php is include it makes a call to the function and displays the html code in it based on the page it is included it. my question is

Is this a good idea or practice?
What alternative do i have to achieving this (other than using templating engines)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a perfect answer, because there are too many ways how to do it.

A good solution would be to separate the view (HTML) from the logic (PHP). Probably [MVC](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller) would be a good answer.

If you want to practice only:

Create a folder and put all your HTML files into that folder. Then you have your PHP file which includes a function (or maybe even a method) that calls that HTML content which you would like to display.
If your HTML content also includes PHP, it would be better not to name it `myFile.php`. In this case call it `myFile.phtml`, so that it is clear to your, it is HTML but part of it is PHP as well.

Comment: Thanks @Reza Saadati. So what i have isnt entirely bad code?

Comment: @Joshua no, it's definitely not bad but you are mixing HTML with PHP which shouldn't be the case. Instead of that, try to get the HTML content with the function `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: Alright @Reza Saadati thanks once again.